Getting 'unrecognized service' error when trying to enable service listed by systemd
System info below.
I have created a service by creating /etc/systemd/system/unison-PaperPortDocs.service.  When I run "systemctl --all list-unit-files 'unison*' I see the following list:
> systemctl --all list-unit-files 'unison*'
UNIT FILE                    STATE    PRESET 
unison-movies-nas.service    enabled  enabled
unison-msdn-download.service disabled enabled
unison-PaperPortDocs.service disabled enabled
unison-picserver-nas.service disabled enabled
unison-plexmedia.service     disabled enabled

5 unit files listed.

But when I try to enable it via 'sudo systemctl enable unison-PaperPortDocs (or with the .service extension), I get an 'unrecognized service' error.
The content is:
[Unit]
Description=Start plex-plexnas1 synchronization

[Service]
Type=simple
User=dennis
Group=dennis
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/auto-unison PaperPortDocs-nas
Restart=on-failure
StandardOutput=file:%h/log_file

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=unison-PaperPortDocs

Permissions are 644, owned by root:root
Any idea what I am doing wrong?
> cat /etc/os-release                                                                                                                               
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 12 (bookworm)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="12"
VERSION="12 (bookworm)"
VERSION_CODENAME=bookworm
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"


try removing Alias=unison-PaperPortDocs - that seems to alias to itself, which seems an odd thing to do (though my systemd knowledge is limited)

Also, Alias's must have the same suffix as the unit file, so your unit file is technically invalid

Thanks, @JaromandaX.  I added the alias when it wasn't working without it.  I've now removed it again.  No operational change.

I rebooted to move the server to a new location, and after restarting, this problem went away.  I never trust when problems just disappear like that.  :(
